# cut command to extract fields

Tags: text-processing, cut

I want to extract date and time from below sequence

```
/hs_nfs/hsfiq/AXZIP-PP567/was_logs/was_admin_logs/start_WPS.log.04-24-2018-08.36.Apr24.zip:ADMU3000I: Server Node_axzip-pp567_AppClusterMember open for e-business;
```

I want to extract fields as

```
Date          Time
04-24-2018   08.36
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us what parts of the name we can rely on. I assume you need toi be able to do this for different values, so what will be constant? Will the date _always_ be after the exact string `start_WPS.log.`? Will the date _always_ be characters 65-74 and the time always be characters 76-80? We can't help you parse a string if you don't explain what parts of the string are variable.

Comment: HI terdon , please see below I tried command                                                 zgrep 'open for' $path/start_WPS.log.*"$yesterdayDate"*|cut -f3,4 -d '.'
    O/p but I dont want - after date                                                                                                      
 04-24-2018-08.36
04-24-2018-22.06

Comment: As said before, please *[edit]* your question and answer the questions I asked.

Comment: yes date will always come after start_WPS.log and  with given set of characters for date and time

Comment: @khuharshree Please don't clarify your question in comments. Edit the text of the question instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -E -e 's/^.*log\.//' -e 's/\.[A-Z].*//' -e 's/([0-9]{4})-/\1 /'
```

The first expression will delete everything in the string up to `log.` just before the date.

The second expression will delete everything from the dot following the time (the only dot that is followed by an upper-case letter).

The third expression will replace the dash after a four-digit number (the year) with a space.

Given the input in the question, this would produce

```
04-24-2018 08.36
```

Comment: getting below error                                                                                   bash-4.2$ zgrep 'open for' $path/start_WPS.log.*"$yesterdayDate"*|sed -E -e 's/^.*log\.//' -e 's/\.[A-Z].*//' -e 's/([0-9]{4})-/\1 /'
sed: Not a recognized flag: E

Comment: I use below command first to list those file contains specific pattern for e.g "open for"   and then apply cut operation to extract DATE & TIME                                                                                                                                bash-4.2$ zgrep 'open for' $path/start_WPS.log.*"$yesterdayDate"*
/pm_nfs/pmfin/AXKIN-PPT4VOW4/was_logs/was_admin_logs/start_WPS.log.04-24-2018-08.36.Apr24.zip:ADMU3000I: Server Node_axkin-ppt4vow4_AppClusterMember open for e-business;

Comment: @khuharshree You may be using an old version of sed. Try replacing -E with -r.

Comment: @khuharshree I'm not going to read any of that. Don't post long pieces of code in comments. If you want to clarify something, do that by editing your question.

Answer (score 0):

If date & time have a unique format in each line that looks like `NN-NN-NNNN-NN.NN` where `N` is a number , then you can use a single grep:

```
$ grep -Eo '[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}[.][0-9]{2}' file1
04-24-2018-08.36
#to remove the third (last) dash you can pipe to sed
$ grep -Eo '[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}[.][0-9]{2}' file1 |sed 's/-/ /3g'
04-24-2018 08.36
```

If you want to also 'bind' above regex after `WPS.log.` you can use gnu grep with -P switch (perl regex support):

```
$ grep -Po '^.*WPS.log.\K[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}[.][0-9]{2}' file1 |sed 's/-/ /3g'
04-24-2018 08.36
#\K == forget everything captured so far == forget ^.*WPS.log.
```